# How to authenticate the user in the wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating a plugin. I need to take some informations from rest api of the wordpress, in this link: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
unfortunately when I try to get some informations from there, my ajax simply do not accept, because only to autheticats users can get informations from there. I tried to use this code:

```
<?php   

    //I am trying to authenticate the user here
    add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'only_authorised_rest_access');

    function only_authorised_rest_access( $result )
    {
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'rest_unauthorised', __( 'Only authenticated users can access the REST API.', 'rest_unauthorised' ), array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() ) );
        }

        return $result;
    }
?>
```

And I am using this function

```
<?php
function wp_favoritar_posts_init() {
       $post_id = 6;
       
       echo "<div class='redimensionar'>";
       echo "<a id='teste' href='?wpfpaction=add&amp;postid=". $post_id ."' title='teste' rel='nofollow'>Favorito</a>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "<script>calculate()</script>"; //I am calling the function for take the rest api here
       
   }


   add_shortcode('favorito', 'wp_favoritar_posts_init');


?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function calculate(){
       var URL = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
       
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "JSON",
           url: URL,
           success: function(data){
               alert('oi');
           },
           error: function (request, status, error) {
               alert(request.responseText);
           }
       });
       
   }
   
</script>
```

But when I execute the page in the browser, appear this menssage:

[image: mensseger]

Someone has a suggestion to take the cookies from the browser for example for authenticate the user?

Comment: check to see if you have a plugin preventing unauthorized access to the API. As seen here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-not-allowing-unauthenticated-requests/

Comment: What the name of this plugin?Because I want to install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a plugin installed that restricts the API access.
based on the message you have posted.

> “Only authenticated users can access the REST API” is not an error
> message that appears anywhere in WordPress core. Are you using a
> plugin to restrict access to the API?

[image: example output of plugin error]

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-not-allowing-unauthenticated-requests/

Comment: what the name of this plugin? Because I want to install

Comment: you probably already have it installed. because you are getting an error that doesn't come from core. You should look at what plugins you have installed already.